# Changing session option after the session is created in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I understand that I can pass options when creating a session. The problem is that I have a wrapper of a Session and I'd like to change the session's config (e.g., intra op parallelism) after the session is created. Is it possible? I didn't find any interface to do it.

Comment: You can set some step-specific options using `tf.RunOptions`. BTW, if you are using distributed Tensorflow `intra_op_parallelism` setting to `Session` is ignored, and you need to set it in `Server(config=...)` instead

Comment: I'm doing this in C++. I have a class which wraps an instance of Session. I'd like to change that instance's option after it has been created.

Comment: TF client API is in `tensorflow/c/c_api.h` and there's doesn't seem to be a method to change options after creating the session